# Blazor Server | NavigationTo login throws NavigationException in custom RoutView

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor-server-side

I have written a custom authentication service that will check if a user is logged in or not. The expected behavior is that the user is redirected to the login page when trying to access a page that they are allowed on without being logged in.

However, I stumbled upon a problem with the redirect to login. According to the result I have gotten from the internet, this fails because the page is not been build yet (server side) The most common mistake is that people use OnInitazlized instead of OnAfter.. Therefor, the Navigationmanager cannot change the header of the URL and redirect to a different page.

My Question is: how can I redirect to the login page within the AppRoutView without getting the error? Did anyone succeed to create a custom implementation for authorization?

My question:
Is there a way I can have my AppRoutView redirect to the login page by using the `@attribute [Authorize]`?

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException: 'Exception of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException' was thrown.'
```

[image: The recieved error message]

```
public class AppRoutView : RouteView
{
    [Inject]
    public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public IAuthenticationService AuthenticationService { get; set; }

    protected override void Render(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        var authorize = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(RouteData.PageType, typeof(AuthorizeAttribute)) != null;
        if (authorize && !AuthenticationService.IsLoggedIn())
        {
            var returnUrl = WebUtility.UrlEncode(new Uri(NavigationManager.Uri).PathAndQuery);
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"login?returnUrl={returnUrl}");//<------ 
        }
        else
        {
            base.Render(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the custom AppRoutView component that is used.

```
@page "/secret"
@attribute [Authorize]

<h3>Secret</h3>
```

The page that trigger the AppRoutView.

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AppRoutView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(MainLayout)"/>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

The App.razor where RoutView is replaced with AppRoutview

```
public interface IAuthenticationService
{
    LoggedInUser LoggedIn { get; }
    Task Initialize();
    Task<bool> Login(string username, string password);
    Task Logout();
    bool IsLoggedIn();
}

public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private const string LoggedInUserNaming = "loggedinuser";
    private readonly NavigationManager _navigationManager;
    private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorageService;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public LoggedInUser LoggedIn { get; private set; }

    public AuthenticationService(
        NavigationManager navigationManager,
        ILocalStorageService localStorageService, IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _navigationManager = navigationManager;
        _localStorageService = localStorageService;
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public bool IsLoggedIn()
    {
        return LoggedIn != null;
    }

    public async Task Initialize()
    {
        LoggedIn = await _localStorageService.GetItemAsync<LoggedInUser>(LoggedInUserNaming);
    }

    public async Task<bool> Login(string username, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            return false;

        if (username == "username" && password == "password")
        {
            //Normal user
            await _localStorageService.SetItemAsync(LoggedInUserNaming, new LoggedInUser(Role.Normal));
            return true;
        }
        else if(password == "password")
        {
            //Admin User
            var user = await _userRepository.IsAdmin(username);
            if (user == null)
                return false;

            await _localStorageService.SetItemAsync(LoggedInUserNaming, new LoggedInUser(user.UserId, Role.Admin));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public async Task Logout()
    {
        LoggedIn = null;
        await _localStorageService.RemoveItemAsync(LoggedInUserNaming);
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo("login");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response to this, but I was just trying to implement your Basic Authentication example.  Not sure if you ever found a resolution for this, but I was able to work around this by adding the ReturnUrl as a parameter of the login page:

```
@code {
[Parameter]
public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
```

}

and then using the following update to the Render method:

```
protected override void Render(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
{
    var authorize = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(RouteData.PageType, typeof(AuthorizeAttribute)) != null;
    if (authorize && AuthenticationService?.User == null)
    {
        var returnUrl = WebUtility.UrlEncode(new Uri(NavigationManager.Uri).PathAndQuery);

        Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        d.Add("ReturnUrl", returnUrl );
        base.RouteData = new RouteData(typeof(Pages.Login), new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>(d));
    }
    base.Render(builder);
}
```